# Online and face-to-face courses - booking and invoicing - how to simplify?

Tags: drupal, crm, moodle

One of the clients has asked for a website, and one of the features offered by the site will be the ability to **book in and pay for the courses**. The courses can be either **online** or **face-to-face**.

For the online-courses, it has been decided that Moodle will be used.

The courses will be **paid for via a CRM**. The same CRM will be used for other purposes as well as invoicing...

We were hoping to enable the **booking process and browsing through the courses on the Drupal website**, but will this become too complicated? Drupal -> CRM -> Moodle?

Also, because there are a certain number of spots for each course, the Enrolment form in Drupal needs to be able to display the number of available spots for the selected course. Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I answered your question related to moodle integration with drupal & in there I have mentioned a module [Commerce Moodle](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_moodle). If you use this module then you get the drupal commerce to handle your selling of courses which will let you explore more of it. Like invoicing, inventory(no of person in your case), collecting extra information at time of buying, bulk operations on users etc..
So options are too many & it will fulfill your need for sure.